# KDE Neon: Grub changes after full upgrade

Tags: grub, upgrade, kde-neon

I started a full upgrade on KDE Neon using recovery mode and grub makes a big change.
whenever I boot up the computer, grub shows the name as "GNU/Linux" instead of "Neon GNU/Linux", uses the gnu-linux class instead of neon class, and there is no quiet or splash settings. I tried editing it manually, but nothing has changed. is there any way I can bring the old configuration of GRUB back?